# Vue.js and changing input fields according to other field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to `Vue.js` and `Vuetify.js`, and are having some trouble doing the following:

```
<v-select v-model="car.type"
    :items="types"
    label="Type"
></v-select>

<div v-if="car.type === 'fiat'">
    <v-text-field v-model="car.km" label="KM"></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field v-model="car.color" label="Color"></v-text-field>
</div>

<div v-else-if="car.type === 'bmw'">
    <v-text-field v-model="car.color.first" label="First color"></v-text-field>
    <v-text-field v-model="car.color.second" label="Second color"></v-text-field>
</div>
```

It works somewhat, and are changing the input fiels according to `type`, but I'm getting the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_vm.car.color.first')"
```

If I change the `v-model` to `car.colorfirst`, without the nested `JSON` object it works. Guess it's because `car.color.first` isn't defined (yet).
But I need the other to work.

What to do, hope it make sense?

Live demo: https://codepen.io/alfredballe84/pen/MBXwKx

Comment: please share live demo or snippet of this ?

Comment: Updated with snippet

Comment: Changing `car.color.first` and `car.color.second` to `car.colorfirst` and `car.colorsecond` make it works, but I need the other solution to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made changes in your html and js

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-form>

      <v-select v-model="car.type" :items="types" label="Type"></v-select>

      <div v-if="car.type === 'fiat'">
        <v-text-field v-model="car.km" label="KM"></v-text-field>
        {{car.km}}
        <v-text-field v-model="car.color" label="Color"></v-text-field>
        {{car.color}}
      </div>

      <div v-else-if="car.type === 'bmw'">
        <v-text-field v-model="car.colorMore.first" label="First color"></v-text-field>
        {{car.colorMore.first}}
        <v-text-field v-model="car.colorMore.second" label="Second color"></v-text-field>
        {{car.colorMore.second}}
      </div>

    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

and in vuejs

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      car: { "type": "fiat",color:"",colorMore:{} },
      types: ["fiat", "bmw"]
    };
  }
});
```

You need to make either empty object(here `colorMore`) to bind or simply use an element(here `color`) to bind .

Forked url in codepen : https://codepen.io/nikleshraut/pen/BPVNMv

Comment: I like Vue.js and peoples who like this.